# what is the correct value to move horizontal rule and join it with vertical rule between minipage?

Tags: boxes, minipage, rules

I am redoing the logos (in word) used by my school, I have managed to align the images and the text, but, I can not find the correct value to move the horizontal rule and join it with the vertical rule. At first sight they seem to be united, but, a little "zoom" notes that they are separated. I have tried with several values in `\rule[...]`, but none has worked. This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}%
\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
\usepackage[margin=0.6in,noheadfoot,papersize={8.5in,13in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % some need a parindent

% box for save dimension
\newsavebox\mysavebox
\sbox\mysavebox{\includegraphics[width=1.45cm,height=1.88cm]{example-image-a}}

% \colelogo
\NewDocumentCommand\colelogo{}{%
\noindent\adjustbox{valign=t}{\noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\ht\mysavebox][t]{0.1\linewidth}%
\usebox\mysavebox%
\end{minipage}}}%

% \coledescript
\NewDocumentCommand\coledescript{}{%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t][\ht\mysavebox][t]{0.7\linewidth}}%
    \begin{center}
        \strut\textsc{\bfseries\Large Colegio XXXXXXXXXX YYYYYY de XXXXX}\par\vspace{0.5pt}
        \emph{Enseñanza Básica}\par\vspace{0.5pt}
        \emph{Formando Personas}\par
        \vfill
        \sffamily Avenida YYYYYY XXXXXXXXX Nª 123 Fono: (12) 325678 XXXXXXXXXXX%
    \end{center}
\end{adjustbox}}%

% \coleyear
\NewDocumentCommand\coleyear{}{%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t][\ht\mysavebox][t]{0.1\linewidth}}%
    \begin{center}
        \strut\bfseries\Large 2018%
    \end{center}
\end{adjustbox}}%

% \colenota
\NewDocumentCommand\colenota{}{%
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\ht\mysavebox][t]{0.1\linewidth}%
    \begin{flushright}
        \tcbox[colback=white,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,%
               boxsep=0mm,arc=2mm,boxrule=0.7pt,title style={draw=none,fill=none}]{%
         \rule{0pt}{\ht\mysavebox}\rule{\wd\mysavebox}{0pt}} % vertical x horizontal
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}}}%

% \colevrule
\NewDocumentCommand\colevrule{}{%
\rule[-0.9\ht\mysavebox]{0.4pt}{1.1\ht\mysavebox}\hspace{-4pt}}

% A headcole command
\NewDocumentCommand\headcole{s}{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\colelogo\coledescript\colevrule\coleyear%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\par\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}\par} % with a star
    {\par\noindent\hfil\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.4pt}\hfil\par} % without a star
}

% A headprueba command
\NewDocumentCommand\headprueba{s}{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\colelogo\coledescript\colevrule\coleyear\colenota
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\par\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}\par} % with a star
    {\par\noindent\hfil\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.4pt}\hfil\par} % without a star
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Use \verb|\headcole|...OK

\headcole
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text

\vspace{1cm}

Use \verb|\headcole*|...OK

\headcole*
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text
\vspace{1cm}

Use \verb|\headprueba|...OK

\headprueba
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text
\vspace{1cm}

Use \verb|\headprueba*|...OK

\headprueba*
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

I use the libertine font and the documents are in `10pt`, `11pt`, `12pt` and the paper size is the one used in my country (they are not enough in the MWE). An image to clarify more:
[image: MWE whit rules not join]
Saludos

Comment: Couldn't you just use a simple `tabularx` for that?

Comment: @marmot: `tabularx` It's an option, but, this will be part of a package that I'll use for tests and exams ... I'm more used to minipage, but, I do not rule it out :)

Comment: I see. (Of course you are loading tcolorbox, which in turn loads tons of other packages, in particular T*i*kZ, which may allow you to build a more straightforward solution, possibly by also loading `tikzpagenodes`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution replaces some of the `\par`s with `\hrule height0pt` which packs tight.  Also put some of the `\rule`s inside `\smash` to remove the vertical space reserved (essentially `\baselineskip`).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}%
%\usepackage[osf]{libertine}% took too long to download
\usepackage[margin=0.6in,noheadfoot,papersize={8.5in,13in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % some need a parindent

% box for save dimension
\newsavebox\mysavebox
\sbox\mysavebox{\includegraphics[width=1.45cm,height=1.88cm]{example-image-a}}

% \colelogo
\NewDocumentCommand\colelogo{}{%
\noindent\adjustbox{valign=t}{\noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\ht\mysavebox][t]{0.1\linewidth}%
\usebox\mysavebox%
\end{minipage}}}%

% \coledescript
\NewDocumentCommand\coledescript{}{%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t][\ht\mysavebox][t]{0.7\linewidth}}%
    \begin{center}
        \strut\textsc{\bfseries\Large Colegio XXXXXXXXXX YYYYYY de XXXXX}\par\vspace{0.5pt}
        \emph{Enseñanza Básica}\par\vspace{0.5pt}
        \emph{Formando Personas}\par
        \vfill
        \sffamily Avenida YYYYYY XXXXXXXXX Nª 123 Fono: (12) 325678 XXXXXXXXXXX%
    \end{center}
\end{adjustbox}}%

% \coleyear
\NewDocumentCommand\coleyear{}{%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t][\ht\mysavebox][t]{0.1\linewidth}}%
    \begin{center}
        \strut\bfseries\Large 2018%
    \end{center}
\end{adjustbox}}%

% \colenota
\NewDocumentCommand\colenota{}{%
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\ht\mysavebox][t]{0.1\linewidth}%
    \begin{flushright}
        \tcbox[colback=white,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,%
               boxsep=0mm,arc=2mm,boxrule=0.7pt,title style={draw=none,fill=none}]{%
         \rule{0pt}{\ht\mysavebox}\rule{\wd\mysavebox}{0pt}} % vertical x horizontal
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}}}%

% \colevrule
\NewDocumentCommand\colevrule{}{%
\rule[-0.9\ht\mysavebox]{0.4pt}{1.1\ht\mysavebox}\hspace{-4pt}}

% A headcole command
\NewDocumentCommand\headcole{s}{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
\colelogo\coledescript\colevrule\coleyear%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
    {\hrule height0pt \smash{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}\par}% with a star
    {\hrule height0pt \hfil\smash{\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.4pt}}\hfil\par}% without a star
}

% A headprueba command
\NewDocumentCommand\headprueba{s}{%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\colelogo\coledescript\colevrule\coleyear\colenota
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\hrule height0pt \smash{\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}}\par} % with a star
    {\hrule height0pt \hfil\smash{\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.4pt}}\hfil\par} % without a star
}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Use \verb|\headcole|...OK

\headcole
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text

\vspace{1cm}

Use \verb|\headcole*|...OK

\headcole*
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text
\vspace{1cm}

Use \verb|\headprueba|...OK

\headprueba
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text
\vspace{1cm}

Use \verb|\headprueba*|...OK

\headprueba*
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you can tell me how to fix the `\rule{0.8\textwidth}{0.4pt}`, it is not centered as it should...

Comment: Replace `\smash` rule for `{\hrule height0pt \begingroup\centering\rule{0.8\linewidth}{0.4pt}\par\endgroup} % without a star` and now it works perfectly ... Thank you very much

Comment: Interestng.  When i did that it was left justified, not centered relative to the page.